# Cant get my program to compile in java?

Tags: java

i've recently had some issues...
I've been folowing some tutorials online and entered the code they tell me too, i modify it a little, and it doesnt work.. This is in Java.

First part of the code that compiled

```
package newjavastoof;

public class NewJavaStoof {
    private String girlName;
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        girlName = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return girlName;
    }
    public void saying()
    {
        System.out.printf("your first girlfriend was %s", getName());
    }
}
```

2nd part of the code that doesnt compile on line 11 and 12

```
package newjavastoof;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stoof {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stoof stoofObject = new Stoof();
        System.out.println("Enter name of first gf here: ");
        String temp = imput.nextLine();
        stoofObject.setName(temp);
        stoofObject.saying();


    }   
}
```

What is incorrect here?
I cant understand, why is there no setName or saying?
Should i declare it?

Comment: Your Stoof class doesn't include a setName method. Should you be creating an instance of NewJavaStoof and using that in your main method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following line

```
Stoof stoofObject = new Stoof();
```

should be

```
NewJavaStoof stoofObject = new NewJavaStoof();
```

Comment: Thank you ;) didnt notice that...

Answer (score 1):

In the first piece of code, your class is named NewJavaStoof, but in the second piece of code, you use class Stoof.

Comment: +1 for beeing the first to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

`Stoof stoofObject = new Stoof();` it should be

`NewJavaStoof stoofObject = new NewJavaStoof ();`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring `NewJavaStoof` but using `Stoof` in your main method? i guess you should replace all `Stoof` with `NewJavaStoof` or rename your `NewJavaStoof` class to `Stoof`

Answer (score 0):

In Stoof you are trying to call setName on stoofObject that is of type Stoof.

```
Stoof stoofObject = new Stoof();
...
stoofObject.setName(temp);
```

Method setName is not defined on Stoof, but on your NewJavaStoof object. Change Stoof to NewJavaStoof and you are done.

```
NewJavaStoof stoofObject = new NewJavaStoof();
...
stoofObject.setName(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance from NewJavaStoof, and not from Stoof..
Stoof does not have the methods setName() and saying()..

use this `NewJavaStoof stoofObject = new NewJavaStoof();`